# WKWebView won't load websites from external domains

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am working on a tabbed application that contains one WKWebView per tab in order to access multiple websites quickly from one app. In the WKWebViews, links with the same domain that the WKWebView is currently on open successfully and show in the WKWebView. Unfortunately, links from external domains do not load, and simply highlight when pressed. Most of the initial websites loaded on the WKWebViews contain an assortment of external links that need to be loaded, however they do nothing.

I have searched for answers online already, but nothing seems to work. I have tried to use `func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` but I can't get it to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code to one of the tabbed view controllers with a WKWebView:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HubViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://somewebsite.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changing Allow Arbitrary Loads under App Transport Security Settings to true/YES in the Info.plist made http links load from other websites such as a google search, but the links on a google sites page are still not loading. I assume this is a problem with google sites, as it works on all the other websites I have tested.

I have also tried using Allows Arbitrary Loads in Web Content and Allows Arbitrary Loads for Media, both to no avail.

I also happen to get this message in the console every time a website loads, perhaps it has something to do with restrictWeb = 1?:

```
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Comment: Are the urls which the web view loads http or https? As due to Apple’s high security standards any web url which is not https will not be loaded unless you specify for them to be allowed which is possible to be done inside of the info plist.

Comment: Ask not what `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` can do for you.  Ask what you can do for App Transport Security.

Comment: The urls are https, but it apparently redirects through an http site www.gstatic.com.

Answer (score 2):

try this :-

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class webView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    
    var webView = WKWebView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.frame = view.frame
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                   self.webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
                                   self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
                                   self.webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
                                   self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
                                   ])
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://www.google.com/")!)
        self.webView.load(request)
    }
    
}
```

**Add in info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for the website I am using, however I tested http site links from a google search, and this does work in that context. I used a proxy tool and found that the links that don't work contain a redirect page with www.gstatic.com. I tried allowing this under exception domains in app transport security settings, but it still does not work. Any thoughts on this?